# What is the best way to process loading a variable number of modals using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am looking to understand the best process rather than working with the code.

I have a varying number of modals generated dynamically based upon the first answer, each modal has a question on. My question is:

**What is the best way to process the current modal and then load the next given the variable number of modals, also knowing when the process has finished. I gather some kind of loop?**

I shall be submitting the data using AJAX and using jQuery to load the modals. I currently have all the modals loaded in the HTML with individual ID's and the first modal displaying.

```
    //Form 1 Submit- Home Page (Sumbits home form and displays diagnosis form)

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    window.location.reload(true);
})

$('#continue_btn').on('click', function () {
$('#enq_2').remove();
  var form = $("#form_1");
  var app = $("[name='appliance']", form).val();


var a = $('#form_1').serialize();
var url = $('#form_1').attr('action');
var type = $('#form_1').attr('method');
console.log(a);
    $('#form_1').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var formElem = $(event.currentTarget);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type        : type,
                        url         : url,
                        data        : a,
                        dataType    : 'json'


                            })
                            .done(function(response){
                                console.log("Done!");
                            //    $('#myModal').modal('show'); //Show Type
                                var enquiry_number = response.enquiry;
                                var questions = response.questions;
                                var question_title = response.question_title;
                                var answ = response.answers;
                                console.log(questions[0].question);

                               $('#customer_enquiry_id').attr('value', enquiry_number)

                                $.each(questions, function (index, value) {
                                    $( ".modals" ).append('<div id="myModal_'+index+'" class="modal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal_title">'+value.question+'</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div id="form_2_check"><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="close_modal_1">Next</button></div></div></div></div></div>');

                                });

                               $('#myModal_0').modal('show'); //Show Type

                                })

                                   .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                    console.log("Fail!", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                                });
                            });
$('#form_1').submit();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a third party library - you can look into the SweetAlert2 library which lets you do this nicely;

https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/